# Tapping Active Abilities when they have summoning sickness?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I put a [Goblin Fireslinger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Goblin%20Fireslinger) onto the battlefield, which would have summoning sickness, can I tap it that turn to use its ability or do I have to wait an extra turn to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Summoning sickness applies to all abilities of a creature that include the tap symbol as a cost, but other abilities with other costs may be played instantly.

Comment: This isn't exactly true. Summoning sickness affects abilities with the **tap symbol** in the cost, but not other abilities that require you to tap a creature. For example, you can tap Heritage Druid to activate its ability in the same turn that it enters the battlefield.